# How to implement an auto search in angular?

Tags: angularjs, search

I am trying to implement autoSearch in angular (+jqeuryEasyUI).
I use mongoDB as the database.

In my controller, I wrote something like that:

```
$scope.$watch('searchInput.text', function() {
  $timeout(functoin() {
    $scope.performSearch($scope.searchInput.text);
    }, 1500)
}
```

The function is called every time the user types another char in the search box input,
and the function: `performSearch(searchInput)` is send a `GET` request to the mongoDB to retrieve data for the current input string.

My problem is that if the user type,say, 3 letters , I want to cancel the request for the first letter and the request for the 2 first letter, and search only the 3 letter together.

That way I used the `Timeout` function, that any change the accuer in this time will cancel the previous request.

How can I mange the request? How do I tell the `$watch` function that if there was any change, don't send the request?

I heard of working with promises but I can't figure out how can it help in this situation.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using AngulaUI-Bootstrap `typeahead` feature? Refer to [this link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It has configuration for timeout, minimum characters for firing search and others. It's east to implement as well.

Comment: thank you! in the end, you were right.. angular-bootstrap has functoin that can handel that..

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller:

```
var timeoutHandle;

$scope.$watch('search', function() {
  $timeout.cancel(timeoutHandle);
  timeoutHandle = $timeout(function() {
    console.log('searching');
  }, 1500)
})
```

This will cancel the previous timeout and set a new one with each change of the input, so that a request will only be sent 1.5 seconds after the last change.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BeLnIWvHp0X1hw8IUC87?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have this kind of functionality, heres sample code:

in controller

```
MyService.delayCall(function() {

            MyService.someFunc(function(data) {
                ...
            });

        },400);
```

in services

```
 delayCallId : 0,
       delayCall : function(call,milisecs) {
           this.delayCallId++;
           var xxx = this;
           var myId = this.delayCallId;
           $timeout(function() {
               if (xxx.delayCallId === myId) {
                   call();
               }
           }, milisecs);
       }
```

---

```
someFuncRequest: 1,
        someFunc : function(callback) {
            this.doyouwantRequest++;
            var xxx = this;
            $http.get(
                    '/some/rest/function?requestId='
                    + this.someFuncRequest).success(
                    function(data, status) {
                        if (xxx.someFuncRequest == data.id) {
                            callback(data);
                        }
                    }).error(function(data, status) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
```